# 30 year old hardwood flooring developing raised areas in living room, dining room, and bedrooms

Tags: flooring

We live in an open concept house with hardwood (not sure what kind) floors that has started to develop raised lips/bumps/strips and various areas.  The flooring is the same in the living room, dining room, and bedrooms.  The surface of the floor is worn (it is 30 years old) but the lips/bumps/strips do not necessarily coincide with particularly worn areas.  The width of the planks is 2 and 1/4 and it is on the 2nd floor of the building with living space underneath.

They are not really big enough to catch in a pic. You can feel them with your feet and also your hands if you get down on the floor. They appear to mostly be along a seam between two boards although in a couple of cases a whole board feels slightly raised.

My concern is moisture but it may be that this is just normal aging occurring over time.  I don't really don't know how to investigate this and would appreciate some help/ideas/wisdom from those out there with experience.

Comment: A picture would be really helpful to see exactly what type and how big these humps are

Comment: How long have you owned the home, if more than one year, I suppose this is the first time it has happened or just the first time you noticed it?

Comment: Added text from a now deleted non-answer that was addressing some of the questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

Without a picture to help discern the issue, it sounds like you have seasonal movement. It is in random areas, with no source of water to make things warp.

I can only figure it is a normal occurrence, especially if the humps are not big enough to see in a picture.

Answer (score 0):

If it's hot and humid where you are, and the air in the house is being affected (not conditioned to keep moisture in the air inside the house down) it may just be from moisture in the air.

It's moisture from *somewhere.* Wood is expanding as it gets wetter, and has run out of room at the edges, so it's humping up where it can as the walls keep it from going out any more.

If not from the air, then usually from the structure, via leaks of some sort.